# How to display redis data in humanfriendly from in javascript

Tags: javascript, redis

I run the following command in redis to set hash and decrement amount of this hash

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset test:key amount 133243112
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hincrbyfloat test:key amount -18978839
"114264273"
127.0.0.1:6379> hincrbyfloat test:key amount -102099438.3
"12164834.69999999999708962"
127.0.0.1:6379> hincrbyfloat test:key amount -12164834.7
"-0.00000000000272848"
```

And when I try to get value in javascript I have got the string "-0.00000000000272848". How can I convert this string to humanfriendly value "0"

Comment: Welcome Oleg, it depends on what you want, for convert that string to humanfriendly value "0" I would recommend you the [Math object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math), also maybe an external library like [Numberal](https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js)

Comment: Hello gengns. I know that Redis sorted float a double 64-bit floating point number to represent the score. "-0.00000000000272848" is represented as an IEEE 754 floating point number. Could u give me advice which method of Math object I have to use?